# Module counting number of $1$'s in a vector

Tags: scoping

I wrote a module which hopes to count the number of $1$'s in a given vector

```
mycount[v_]:=Module[{v0=v},s=0;Do[If[v0[[i]]=1,s=s+1],{i,1,Length[v0]}];s]
```

However, no matter how I change it around, it returns the number $0$ for the example vector {1,1,1,2} I used, can someone point out what is wrong becauuse I cannot see it?

Comment: `mycount[v_] := Module[{v0 = v, s = 0},
  Do[If[v0[[i]] == 1, s = s + 1], {i, 1, Length[v0]}]; s]`

Comment: Please show a complete MWE including the call itself.  btw, there is a function called `Count` in Mathematica already.

Comment: @Syed Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nasser Nvm, I already solved it thanks to the comment above. I knew of the Count function, I was just practising creating modules and doing loops. Thanks anyway!

Comment: `Count[{1, 1, 1, 2}, 1]` would count 1s. I think you should look at the [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor himself for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a faster alternative that uses vectorized operations:

```
mycount2[v_] := Length[v] - Total[Unitize[v - 1]]
```

Compare (with `v0[[i]] = 1` changed to `v0[[i]] == 1`):

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, 10^6];

mycount[list] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.680935, 333888}
> ```

```
mycount2[list] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.012579, 333888}
> ```

And a built in function:

```
Count[list, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.033939, 333888}
> ```

Comment: Interesting that the user-defined `mycount2` outperforms built-in `Count` here.